# Chrome DevTools: how to change order of snippets?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

By snippets I mean: Sources tab > Snippets left panel.

I wonder if there's another way to change their order since *drag & drop* does not seem to work (at least, locally on my Chrome 61).